# Country/Region/City DB

Tags: php, database

Does anybody knows where I can download or buy multilanguage database of Countries/Regions/Cities?

Multilanguage means that names of cities and countries should be on their local language.

Or maybe exists any service with this functionality?

Comment: Question: What happens if the people of a Country/Region/City has more nations, like cities in Northern Ireland or cities in the Transylvanian part of Romania? Do you need to have the names of these places in all their native languages, or do you need their names only in one language. If you only want their names in the original language of the given territory, what will be your approach with Switzerland, where the natives have more official languages?

Comment: I need their names only in one language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.geonames.org/ is your choice. It contains all the data you need, countries, country names in every languages, country names in their language, etc.

You can downlaod these at http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ . Obviously, it will need a little work to use on a website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve in an easier way a database of all the countries/regions/cities in the world in English, you can find out at least a language spoken for each country and you can use google translate (of course you'll write a web crawler to get the information automatically) to translate the name of the country/region/city from English to the given language. I know this is still a lot of work, but you can buy a database of locations in English relatively cheaply or maybe you can even find the data for free somewhere, writing a web crawler is not a difficult job if it only sends requests to google translate. Finding out the languages of all the countries is not that difficult. There are not so many crawlers. I wish you good work and success.